# Eigenvalues and eigenspaces for the map $T(z,w)=(w,-z)$ on $\mathbb R^2$

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

> Find all the eigenvalues and corresponding eigenspaces for $T(z,w)=(w,-z)$ for all $(z,w)$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

So I would need to find all the values $x$ for which $T(z,w)=x(z,w)=(w,-z).$

So $xz=w$ and $xw=-z$

So $x$ must be zero? Or $z$ or $w$ are zero?

I'm a bit confused.

Comment: No, you must have $x^2 w+w = 0$ and $x^2z +z = 0$. Since $(w,z) \neq 0$ you must have $x^2+1 = 0$.

Comment: Note: the matrix corresponding to this transformation is
$$
A = \pmatrix{0&1\\-1&0}
$$

Answer (score 0):

By definition, an eigenvector should be non-zero. So if $x = 0$, then $0 = (w,-z)$, so $w=z=0$, so this gives never rise to an eigenvector. Also, if $w = 0$, then the above equations imply $z = 0$.

So we can assume that they are non-zero. So 
$$xw = x^2z = -z \Rightarrow (x^2+1)z = 0 \Rightarrow x^2+1 = 0$$
But $x$ is real, so there are no solutions.

Notice that this method is not particularly nice. A much nicer method is by computing the characteristic polynomial of the linear transformation (are you familiar with that?)